# C : while( scanf("%d",&num) != 1 ) infinite loop

Tags: c, scanf, infinite-loop

hope you could help me with this
I have to use `scanf` to read and validate inputs...
I've tried this code:

```
int num = 0;
while( scanf("%d",&num) != 1 || num < 3 || num > 9){
printf("Enter new num: ");
}
```

when I input numbers it works great but when I input any other character it goes into infinite loop instead of asking for new input...

```
Enter new num: Enter new num: Enter new num: Enter new num:
Enter new num: Enter new num: Enter new num: Enter new num:
Enter new num: Enter new num: Enter new num: Enter new num:
```

any ideas?

thanks

Comment: You just learned a good reason to never use `scanf()` - when you enter unexpected input, it gets stuck.

Comment: @AndrewHenle as I mentioned.. unfortunately I have to use it..

Comment: An alternative would be to use `sscanf` on a string you read with `fgets`.

Comment: If `a` is in the input stream, scanf sees the `a` but does not read it (because it can't be parsed as part of an `int`) and returns 0 without writing a value to `num`.  Since the condition is true, it repeats that process and the `a` is never consumed.  You need to discard the invalid data.

Comment: Sorry for asking, but are you writing unreadable code on purpose? It's a serious question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the invalid data from the input buffer. for example

```
int num = 0;
while( scanf("%d",&num) != 1 || num < 3 || num > 9){
    scanf( "%*[^\n]%*c" );
    printf("Enter new num: ");
}
```

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int num = 0;

    printf("Enter new num: ");
    
    while( scanf("%d",&num) != 1 || num < 3 || num > 9){
        scanf( "%*[^\n]%*c" );
        printf("Enter new num: ");
    }
    
    printf("num = %d\n", num );
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter new num: 1
Enter new num: A
Enter new num: 10
Enter new num: 5
num = 5
```

Comment: This almost works, but it doesn't handle `EOF`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell He is going tp continue the loop until a valid number will be entered.

Comment: If the input stream is closed, then a valid number will never be entered.  In that case, terminating the program is correct behavior.  But more importantly, you need to make the beginner aware of the issue and show how to deal with it.

Comment: @WilliamPursell No for a beginner it is entirely unimportant what you wrote. What he need is to get a finite loop that allows to ignores non numbers.

Comment: Then you are encouraging bad practice.  Handling EOF is not "unimportant".  It is a major hurdle that beginners struggle with because it is often ignored.  Don't perpetuate bad practice.  Just modify the code to demonstrate how to handle the input properly.

Comment: @WilliamPursell The question is not about how to process EOF. The question is about how to make the shown loop finite when a non digit is entered.

Comment: @BenEz Be aware that this program does not behave well.  Consider the behavior when you run it like `echo foo | ./a.out`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Is it a joke? He even does not understand what  you want to say.:)

Comment: The question is about how to read and validate input.  The OP presented a potential solution that is seriously flawed.  Rather than demonstrate how it ought to be done, you have provided a "solution" that will just lead to more confusion later.  Yes, I think your answer is a joke.  The modifications you need to make are trivial, and I do not understand why you think it is better to let to OP move forward with a bad approach.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I appreciate your concern about EOF but in my assignment is isn't a possible case. thank you

Comment: Vlad and William, it's important to realize that there can not be a perfect answer here.  If you wanted to do *truly* robust input, you wouldn't be using `scanf` in the first place.  So if the assignment is, "Do 'mostly' robust input, but you have to use `scanf`", then we're automatically in an imponderably subjective grey area.  Must we handle a user who types letters instead of digits?  Yes.  Must we handle a user to types a line of 1,000 characters without typing a newline?  Who knows.  Must we handle a user who manages to enter EOF?  Who knows.

Comment: And, yes, new learners eventually need to learn about all these issues — but no learner can learn everything at once, so it's again debatable whether it is or isn't mandatory for new learner A to learn about issue B *today*, or whether that's just as well put off until next week's lesson.